# SVN Location Change

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am using eclipse indigo for my application. My problem is I have taken checkout of the project from one repository of svn. Now the svn location is moved to another repository. I need to change my svn subversion for getting any update or committing my code. My question is, am I having the only option of taking checkout again or eclipse having any option to change svn location of existing codebase.

Comment: Can you try:  Right click on project->Team , If project is already shared, unshare/delink it from svn repo. Create new repo with new url and now try linking your project with this repo

Answer (score 1):

You can use `svn relocate` to point the workspace to a new repository. Please check the following page for more details:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.relocate.html